# compact(): undefined variable in zendframework

Tags: php, zend-framework

i install zend framework using composer on my localhost. I use the built in php server from xampp to deploy my zendframework application. After installation there is an error log of "compact(): Undefined variable: extras in C:\Users\oyela\Documents\zend\path\to\install\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\Helper\HeadLink.php on line 404"

I have tried to use different namespace in the HeadLink.php file:

```
$attributes = compact('rel', 'type', 'href', 'media', 'conditionalStylesheet', 'extras');
```

I expect to have the zend index page displayed but it is displayed with this error log.

Answer (score 3):

Under PHP 7.3 we see the following logged:
PHP Notice: compact(): Undefined variable: extras in src\Helper\HeadLink.php on line 413

A quick fix replaces lines 408-413 with:

```
$attributes = compact('rel', 'type', 'href', 'media', 'conditionalStylesheet');

if ($args && is_array($args[0])) {
$attributes['extras'] = array_shift($args);
}
```

You can find more details about this on 
[PHP 7.3 issue with compact() in HeadLink.php #172](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/issues/172#issue-388080603)